# Bluetooth (3) keyboard connected to bluetooth (4) computer. Does the computer draw more power?

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-3.0

I have both a computer and a phone that support bluetooth low energy (4.0). I’m looking to buy a wireless solar keyboard that uses bluetooth 3.0. What will happen in this connection? Does the fact the keyboard doesn’t use low energy bluetooth mean more battery will be required from the computer/phone, or does that simply mean the keyboard will spend more energy than if it used bluetooth 4.0 but the paired device will still spend as much energy as with every other bluetooth low energy connection?